# What type of installation shall I use to install Condor on 4 servers running CentOS

Tags: centos, hpc, condor

I plan to install Condor on 4 servers running CentOS5 to form a HPC cluster using those 4 dedicated machines can I use the Red hat RPMs files to install Condor or is there another files and what type of installation shall I used and is it the same steps with different configurations or a different installation steps?

This the installations steps that I used: http://bit.ly/A7Xddl

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for CentOS 5 you should use the rhel5 RPMs distributed by the Condor team.  The install instructions you link to are correct.